# How to remove highlighting on tags HTML when selected

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Please how i can to remove highlighting on HTML tags when selected, on Visual Studio Code?

[image: Tag highlighting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In settings.json:

```
"[html]": {
    "editor.matchBrackets": false
}
```

Comment: You can access `settings.json` by typing ⌘, (probably ctrl+, on windows)

Comment: Ok but highlighting now is on the word, es. BODY, HTML

Comment: @Stew `"[html]": {
        "editor.occurrencesHighlight": false,
    }`